# How to combine multiple rows in pandas with shared column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using pandas to read json objects and output the data as csv files.

Currently I have generated a dataframe with data as shown below:
[image: Initial data]

There are hundreds of lines, and every two of them share the same two unique_key values. I would like to aggregate the rows with the same unique_key values into a single line, and convert the data into a csv file.

I tried to duplicate data into two identical dataframes and outer-join them:

```py
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data_list)
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data_list)
pd.merge(df_1, df_2, how='outer', on=[unique_key_1,unique_key_2], sort=True)
```

For the 'how' field, I tried all available options, and they either duplicate the rows, or create columns with names like:
COL_1_x COL_1_y

Here is the output that I would like to achieve:

[image: Desired Result]

I am wondering if there is any possible solution for this merging problem?

I believe groupby won't work as I need to export the dataframe into csv files.

Also, i am not sure if duplicating the the data into two identical dataframes and outer-join them is the right approach.

Highly appreciate any answer that is practical!

Comment: You have it correct using outer (this should give you all the rows in the first data frame AND all the rows in the second dataframe).  Your issue is that when you merge two dataframes, the column names overlap (because they are the same in both dataframes).  So when you are done, just go back and rename the overlapping columns or remove them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is a groupby:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame([[1,5,10,np.nan,5,np.nan],[2,1,10,np.nan,5,np.nan],[1,5,np.nan,1,np.nan,-10],[2,1,np.nan,1,np.nan,-10]],columns=['u1','u2','c1','c2','c3','c4'])
df = data.groupby(['u1','u2'])['c1','c2','c3','c4'].sum().reset_index()
```